# Model illumination

Tags: javascript, three.js, light

After loading a model with OBJMTLLoader it is automatically set as a MeshLambertMaterial and unfortunatelly i can't get it to be in full color and textures look much darker. I have some problems with setting the correct light in the scene.

I have added an ambient light but its not enough:

```
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff ));
```

Is it possible to turn off the 'luminance' and make the mesh lambert material visible without any light in the scene?

Comment: `MeshLambertMaterial` requires a light in the scene. only `MeshBasicMaterial` does not require a light.

Comment: Is there a way to convert materials?

Comment: rename the material and take out the attributes that give you an error.

Comment: Or create your own ShaderMaterial. If you only want color and textures it should be quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to recreate material, one is open your model file and change material here in source file manually. Or when usilg object loader or json loader, use "`for`" syntax to go trough each material and set another values

```
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
jsonLoader.load(model, addthree1ToScene);

                      function addthree1ToScene( geometry, materials ) 
                      {
                          var materiall = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials ); 


                          for ( var i = 0; i < materials.length; i ++ )
                          {
                           var material = materials[i];
                              material.side = THREE.DoubleSide; /// there you can set attributes
                          }

                          three1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, materiall );



                          three1.position.set(x,y,z);



                          scene.add( three1 );
                          console.log(three1);

                      }
```